# How to disable prepending '<!-- -->' when passing const string into component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have component like this:

```
const CustomTitle = (props: any) => {
    return <title>FIX - {props.text ?? `Default text`}</title>
}
```

When I use it inside my `<Head>` tag (`next/head`) as `<CustomTitle />` I get this output:
`<title>FIX - <!-- -->Default text</title>`

How can I escape this `<!-- -->` prepending?